# Magento 2 - Request sample for carts/mine (GET)

Tags: api, rest, magento2

I try to call the carts/mine GET route of the Magento 2 REST API, but it does not show a request sample in the [documentation](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/).

[image]

It says "Returns information for the cart for a specified customer."

But how do I specify the customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include a customer bearer to call this API. You can get it from calling `/integration/customer/token`. Here is an example:

```
POST https://<host>/rest/V1/integration/customer/token
Content-Type: application/json

{"username":"<email>", "password":"<password>"}
```

It will return a customer token looks like this:

```
"3zznrpsthn6m3dheeacyfe3xzdjryd3y"
```

Then use this bearer token to call `cart/mine` API:

```
GET {{host}}/rest/V1/carts/mine/
Authorization: Bearer 3zznrpsthn6m3dheeacyfe3xzdjryd3y
Content-Type: application/json
```

And this is an example response:

```
{
  "id": 3354,
  "created_at": "2023-02-15 03:44:37",
  "updated_at": "2023-02-15 03:44:37",
  "is_active": true,
  "is_virtual": false,
  "items": [],
  "items_count": 0,
  "items_qty": 0,
  "customer": {
    "id": 145,
    "group_id": 1,
    "default_billing": "140",
    "default_shipping": "140",
    "created_at": "2021-09-13 06:47:49",
    "updated_at": "2022-10-11 08:03:42",
    "created_in": "en_US",
    "email": "????",
    "firstname": "????",
    "lastname": "????",
    "store_id": 2,
    "website_id": 1,
    "addresses": [
      {
        "id": 140,
        "customer_id": 145,
        "region": {
          "region_code": "????",
          "region": "????",
          "region_id": 860
        },
        "region_id": 860,
        "country_id": "??",
        "street": [
          "???"
        ],
        "telephone": "????",
        "city": "????",
        "firstname": "????",
        "lastname": "????",
        "default_shipping": true,
        "default_billing": true,
      }
    ],
    "disable_auto_group_change": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
      "is_subscribed": false
    }
  },
  "billing_address": {
    "id": 10058,
    "region": null,
    "region_id": null,
    "region_code": null,
    "country_id": null,
    "street": [
      ""
    ],
    "telephone": null,
    "postcode": null,
    "city": null,
    "firstname": null,
    "lastname": null,
    "customer_id": 145,
    "email": "????",
    "same_as_billing": 0,
    "save_in_address_book": 0
  },
  "orig_order_id": 0,
  "currency": {
    "global_currency_code": "HKD",
    "base_currency_code": "HKD",
    "store_currency_code": "HKD",
    "quote_currency_code": "HKD",
    "store_to_base_rate": 0,
    "store_to_quote_rate": 0,
    "base_to_global_rate": 1,
    "base_to_quote_rate": 1
  },
  "customer_is_guest": false,
  "customer_note_notify": true,
  "customer_tax_class_id": 3,
  "store_id": 1,
  "extension_attributes": {
    "shipping_assignments": []
  }
}
```